# Web Crawler occurred java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: java, web, web-crawler

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
at TestHttpClient.testURL3(TestHttpClient.java:196)
at TestHttpClient.main(TestHttpClient.java:226)
```

I set useragent/cooike and other setting like Browser but it's still such this exception.I test other website program is OK , so i guess it's may be anti crawling strategy.
I hope you can help me find out the reason for the error or what should i do.
Thx!!!!!

Comment: Can you explain us a little bit more what you want to achive or show us some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

ok,i konw why my program was err.Because the GFW force to disconnect the TCP connection.